# WM_GESTURE: retrieve all fingers?

Tags: winapi, touch, gesture-recognition, gestures

I'm using WM_GESTURE to manipulate my 3D scene, and i'd like to perform different gestures if i'm panning with 1 finger or if i'm panning with 2 fingers.

I know that i could get the touches and do everything by myself, but i like to use gestures because it interprets correctly all the touches and transform them into gestures.

How can I, after receiving a GID_PAN event, detect wether the user is using 1 or 2 fingers and its positions?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out the answer.

After trying to figure it out all day before posting a question here, now i've found [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20121105223518/http://www.webworldarticles.com/e/a/title/Use-the-Pan-Gesture-to-Move-an-Object/) which explains the function of `ullArguments`. It will store the distance between the fingers when i'm panning. so if it's a single finger panning, ullArguments will be 0; otherwise, it will be a positive number.